# OpenForm form Search with condition on ID field to open 1 of 3 forms based on Type field in Search form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access-2016

My database is organized with a main central navigation form ("Main Menu"). Clicking on any of the nav buttons on the left side will take users to a form with 1 to many subforms. For example, clicking on the Health Claims navigation button will take users to the Health Claims Form with seven tabs (each tab is a different subform).

I have created a Search page with `[IDENT_NUM]` and [TYPE] that displays different types of claims records-each claim type will go to its specific claim form (one of three options). I am trying to click on the `[IDENT_NUM]` field in the search table and have it take me to one of the three forms depending on the [TYPE] field. My Search page is a search subform in a "Search" Form then dropped into my Main Menu. So, if I click on ID = 123 with Type = Health, I would like to be taken to the Health Claims of ID 123.

My search is set up to show all claims so it can be seen which clients have multiple claims and what types of claims.

My three forms are Credit, Health Claims, Life Claims
Credit form corresponds to TYPE: "Policy" OR "Certificate"
Health form corresponds to TYPE: "Health" 
Life form corresponds to TYPE:"Disablity" OR "Life"

I tried adding macro and VBA (independent of one another) 'OpenForm' and I could not get the VBA to work at all but the macro would open either a blank form only or an existing record that did not match the `[IDENT_NUM]` clicked or the type.

```
Private Sub IDENT_NUM_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm"Health Claims", , , 
"IDENT_NUM = '" & (Me.IDENT_NUM) & "'"
End Sub
```

I created an OpenForm macro in the OnClick property of my field IDENT_NUM in my search table with the following `Where Condition =[IDENT_NUM]=[Forms]![Main Menu]![Health Claims]![IDENT_NUM].` This macro just opens a blank record which will be great when I want to do that (I will use buttons) but for now, I want to go to the applicable form type based on the [IDENT_NUM] and [TYPE] selected in the Search Table. If I change the `Where Condition =[IDENT_NUM]`, it will take me to the same record regardless of the [IDENT_NUM] selected.  I also tried adding IF, ELSE IF too but nothing worked for actually getting me my results.

I think the problem in the macro is my navigation but I am not positive how to fix it. I also am not sure if I can just open the form or if I need to add the specific subform with the ID field...do I need to do the same for the Type? They are in different subforms currently but I could change that if needed.

I would really appreciate the help and guidance.